# Overwrite properties in angular forEach

Tags: angularjs

I imagine this is an easy thing to do, but I wasnt able to find the information I was looking for through google. I have `popupProperties` which is just default stuff. I then call to the service which returns specific overrides depending on the popup. How can I iterate through all of the service's overrides and apply them to the `popupProperties`?

```
var popupProperties = getDefaultPopupProperties();
var popupOverrides= popupService.getPopupOverrides(currPopupId);

angular.forEach(popupOverrides, function(popupProperty, propertyName){
    //replace defaults with popupData's properties
});
```

Comment: Do you mean [`angular.extend`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.extend)? e.g. `angular.extend(popupProperties, popupOverrides)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should have a look at the solution of **Josh David Miller** which uses the extend method of angular ([documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.extend)).

```
var defaults = {name:'John',age:17,weight:55};
var overrides = {name:'Jack',age:28,color:'brown'};
var props = angular.extend(defaults, overrides);

// result
props: {
    name:'Jack',
    age:28,
    weight:55,
    color:'brown'
}
```

The values are copied in the defaults variable. There is no need of using the return value (var props =).

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean both functions are returning objects with a number of properties (as opposed to an array).

If so, the following should work - just JavaScript, nothing AngularJS specific:

```
for (var attrname in obj2) { obj1[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
```

See this question for more details [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: This did work, however it is not the "angular" way of doing it. +1 for the working answer though.